# Perforce: How to see changes in current version and previous version

Tags: perforce

How to see changes in current version and previous version
Suppose My current changelist is 4321, how we can see

1. which files are being changed?
2. what are those changes in each file?

Comment: How is your "previous" changelist more than 5000 changelists after your current changelist?  Usually the previous changelist would simply be current - 1.

Comment: Please ignore number and difference, Its just assumption.

Comment: Is the intention to get the differences *in* each of those changelists (i.e. the differences between each changelist and the immediately previous changelist), or the differences *between* those two changelists?  The phrasing isn't very clear and the example makes it hard to triangulate the intent.

Comment: Intention is just to get difference between immediate checkin only.

Comment: I'll edit the question and my answer appropriately -- asking "what changed in changelist 4321" is very simple, but stipulating "previous is 9876" just makes it confusing since that's an impossible situation.  :)

Answer (score 3):

To get detailed information about a single specific changelist, including which files were changed in that changelist and what the differences were, use `p4 describe`:

```
p4 describe 4321
```